# Replacing a sensor in an old Logitech Cordless MouseMan Optical mouse

Tags: mouse

I have this Logitech Cordless MouseMan Optical mouse which is probably 16 years old. I really like the ergonomics of it and also it can be taken apart easily (lots of screws, every part accessible and big enough) which allowed me to replace malfunctioning micro-switches for particular buttons.

I have a problem though - I'm using it on an old mouse pad which is falling apart. Unfortunately the mouse doesn't work well at all on other mouse pads available these days on the market (I tried at least 4 with different types of materials.) The sensor "gets lost" after I move the mouse too rapidly and stays in one place instead of moving accordingly, or it ends up slightly away from a position on the screen you'd expect it to be.

Would it make sense to replace the sensor, or a diode at least? I'm not really experienced or don't have professional equipment, just a regular soldering iron.

The sensor is on a separate PCB:

[image]

[image]

Same thing flipped upside down:

[image]

This PCB is then attached to the rest of the mouse through this connector on the main board:

[image]

Comment: Your optical IC appears to be a fourier plane device to my eye (holes placed in suspicious locations is consistent with that idea), though I've no real idea. So I did a quick search and found [this page](http://spritesmods.com/?art=mouseeye) and [this page](https://www.bidouille.org/hack/mousecam) discussing approximately what you face. If I'm right, you'll need a specific pattern. I don't think any pad will work. Replacing it would require a thorough understanding of the optical system itself as well as all of the circuitry using it. Probably beyond my crystal ball's ability.

Comment: Can you add a photo of the mouse pad? You might be able to laser-print a suitable pattern onto a self-adhesive laser film or sheet label and use that.

Comment: I found hints that you can use an Everglide Giganta mouse pad with that mouse.  Everglide is still around.  See if you can get a Giganta pad.

Comment: try using the mouse on printed paper, like newspaper ... the mouse needs to see contrasting patterns ... it gets those from a rough surface that is lit at a low angle

Comment: I think i start to understand this. It's not really the material and the texture of it that matters but the "look" of the print, is that right? All the mouse modern pads i tried out were actually black. So the basic idea is to have a contrast pattern on it? Here's the look of my old pad the mouse works fine with: https://freeimage.host/i/J8gFCQ